# Doubt in the geometric interpretation of Newton's method of calculating the roots of the equation $f(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This is a question from Rudin(trying to prove the newtons method of calculating the roots of the function) and which aks me to state the geometric intuition of :

$$x_n=x_{n-1}-\frac{f(x_{n-1})}{f'(x_{n-1})}$$

I know that the the line to the tangent at the graph at the point $(x_1,f(x_1))$ has the equation $y = f(x_1)+f'(x_1)(x-x_1)$ and it crosses the graph at the point $x_2$ which is given by the above equation.

Now, while looking at the equation,I found something like this:

$\frac{x_1.f(x_1+h)-f(x_1)(x_1+h)}{f(x_1+h)-f(x_1)}=x_2$ which forces me to think of the exterior division formula where $m=f(x_1+h)$ and $n= f(x_1)$ and the equation assumes the form $\frac{m.x_1-n(x_1+h)}{m-n}=x_2$.Since $x_1 \in (\alpha,b)$ and $f(\alpha)=0(f(b)>0)$ and the point $x_2$ is the exterior point , so $x_2$ is closer to $\alpha$.Why am I getting something similar to the exterior division formula?

Comment: Which "exterior point theorem" ? And what is $h$ ?

Comment: Sorry I meant the exterior division formula

Comment: @Yves what I feel is that we are externally dividing the line segment joining $x_1$ and $x_1+h$ and obtaining $x_2$ which is close to $\alpha$

Comment: The ratio in which we are dividing is $f(x_1+h)$ and $f(x_1)$

Comment: I see no similarity between the division and Newton's formulas. Please explain.

Comment: With some manipulation I got something of the form $(mx_1-n(x_1+h))/(m-n)=x_2$ .Isn't this similar to the formula we get when we divide the line joining $x_1$ and $x_1+h$ in the ratio $m:n$?

Comment: Indeed. But I still see no connection with Newton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no big mystery in Newton's method.

We know that a smooth function is well approximated locally by its tangent, and it is easy to find the "root" of the tangent.

Likewise, you could use the osculatrix parabola corresponding to the Taylor development to the second order, and so on.

---

The secant method is based on the idea that a smooth function is well approximated by a chord. A three-points quadratic approximation is used in Muller's method.